# Scala-test having issues with read file

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm working on *Scalatest* where I need to validate a few parameters against my inputs(in Excel file). My problems are:

1. How to insert/read excel sheet using Scalatest
2. How to validate the outputs against the corresponding input from excel

**More details**

Suppose for test case,on clicking on webpage XYZ,parameter/property "ads" should "Y" is fetched and I have given the condition that test case should be PASSED if excel sheet (having property "ads" is "Y" for Webpage XYZ),matches with the parameters fetched from webpage

Any pointers will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spoiwo](https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo) or [Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org/) to read the `excel` files. You can follow any simple tutorials on how to read and write to `excel` file using `apache poi`. [Here](https://github.com/kornsanz/SparkSolutions/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/shankar/excel/ReadExcelFile.scala) simple example of reading files from `excel`.

You can test in `scalatest` after retrieving the values from excel and write back the test results.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: did this helped ?